# Save 4D matrix to a file with high precision (%1.40f) in Matlab

Tags: matlab, save, precision

I need to write 4D matrix (M-(16x,101x,101x,6x) to a file with high precision ('precision'-'%1.40f') in MATLAB.

I've found `save('filename.mat', 'M' );` for multidimensional matrix but precision cannot be set (only -double). On the other hand I've found `dlmwrite('filename.txt', M, 'delimiter', '\t', 'precision', '%1.40f');` to set the precision but only limited to 2-D array.

Can somebody suggest a way to tackle with my problem?

Comment: bare in mind that you can `reshape` your 4-D array to 2D and back if needed ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is the point in storing 40 digits of fractional part if double precision number in MATLAB keeps only 16 of them?
Try this code:

```
t=pi
whos
fprintf('%1.40f\n',t)
```

The output is

```
Name      Size            Bytes  Class     Attributes
t         1x1                 8  double              

3.1415926535897931000000000000000000000000
```

The command `save('filename.mat', 'M' );` will store numbers in their binary representation (8 bytes per double-precision number). This is unbeatable in terms of space-saving comparing with plain-text representation.

As for the 4D shape the way **j_kubik** suggested seems simple enough.

Answer (score 1):

I always thought that `save` will store exactly the same numbers you already have, with the precision that is already used to store them in matlab - you are not losing anything. The only problems might be disk space consumption (too precise numbers?) and closed format of .mat files (cannot be read by outside programs). If I wanted to just store the data and read them with matlab later on, I would definitely go with `save`.
`save` can also print ascii data, but it is (as `dlmwrite`) limited to 2D arrays, so using `dlmwrite` will be better in your case.

Another solution:

```
tmpM = [size(M), 0, reshape(M, [], 1)];
dlmwrite('filename.txt', tmpM, 'delimiter', '\t', 'precision', '%1.40f');
```

reading will be a bit more difficult, but only a bit ;)

Then you can just write your own function to write stuff to a file using `fopen` & `fprintf` (just as `dlmwrite` does) - there you can control every aspect of your file format (including precision).

Something I would have done if I really cared about precision, file-size and execution time (this is probably not the way for you) would be to write a mex function that takes a matrix parameter and stores it in a binary file by just copying raw data buffer from matlab. It would also need some indication of array dimensions, and would probably be the quickest (not sure if `save` doesn't already do something similar).

Comment: Nice! However `M(:)` might be neater than `reshape(M, [], 1)`.

Comment: @pm89 I agree that `M(:)` is neater but you have to do it with shape of the new array in mind. Like this `tmpM = [size(M), 0, M(:)'];` or this `tmpM = [size(M); 0; M(:)];`.

Comment: I am unsure what is the actual implementation behind it but `M(:)` and `reshape(M, [], 1)` doe exactly the same. I prefer the latter because of superstition that implementation of `reshape` might not require copying entire array on reshaping. If I have a moment, one day I will investigate the difference.